# How to convert cell array of mixed doubles and hexadecimals with leading "0x" to 2D array of doubles?

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv, parsing, cells

**My objective is to parse a tab separated data set containing a mix of numerical columns and hexadecimal columns into a double matrix where all values have been converted to floats.**

I am working in Matlab.  I have a tab-separated file containing a mix of numerical columns and hex columns, e.g.:

```
 A | B | C |     D
---|---|---|-----------
0x3|  1|  2| 0x118c0832
---|---|---|-----------
0x3|  3|  4| 0x118c0832
---|---|---|-----------
0x3|  5|  6| 0x118c0832
---|---|---|-----------
0x3|  7|  8| 0x118c0832
```

To parse the data, I utilize the `textscan()` function like so (for simplicity we will skip past extraction of the headers and pretend the file starts on line 2):

```matlab
fileID = fopen('data.dat');
formatString = '%s %f %f %s';
data = textscan(fileID,formatString);
```

*Note: `textscan()` does not accept the hex conversion character, `%x`.*

At this point I am left with a 1x4 cell array, `data`, where `data{1,3}` corresponds to a 4x1 cell array containing the contents of column C, i.e.: 
 `data{1,3} == {2; 4; 6; 8}`.

Once all values are numerical, a simple `data = cell2mat(data)` converts my data to the desired 4x4 array; however, I am struggling to find the simplest and fastest way to convert the hex cells to floats due to the leading `'0x'`.

I've attempted to put something together using a combination of `regexp()` and `hex2dec()`, but that generally involves creating more and more cell arrays, so any solution seems convoluted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert these values to a float? 0x3 would have no equivalent in a float. Why not just have them be strings?

Comment: @Flynn Wouldn't the float equivalent of `0x3` just be `3.0`?

Comment: No, you need to remove the x's and c's, like the answers mentioned below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the `0x` in the call to [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) like so:

```
fileID = fopen('data.dat');
formatString = '0x%s %f %f 0x%s';
data = textscan(fileID,formatString);
```

And then convert the columns with [`hex2dec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2dec.html) (for integer results) or [`hex2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hex2num.html) (for double-precision floating-point results):

```
data{1} = hex2dec(data{1});
data{4} = hex2dec(data{4});
data = [data{:}];
```

And the result:

```
data =

           3           1           2   294389810
           3           3           4   294389810
           3           5           6   294389810
           3           7           8   294389810
```

Comment: thanks, this is my favorite solution as I can knock out a whole step by simply modifying `formatString`.  I was unaware of this replace-like function of the format string and it's not in the examples.  Do you know where it is documented?

Comment: @CollinGonzalez: It's mentioned at the *very end* of the [`formatSpec` input argument description](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec), "Literal Text to Ignore" bullet.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply trim all the 0x values off and convert to hex using a lambda expression ([anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)), with `cellfun`.

```
fileID = fopen('data.dat');
formatString = '%s %f %f %s';
data = textscan(fileID,formatString);

f = @(x) hex2num(x(3:end));

data{1} = cellfun(f, data{1});
data{4} = cellfun(f, data{4});
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have the 4th column in hand and name it as `dummyStr`:

```
dummyStr = {'0x218c0832','0x138c0832','0x518c0832','0x318c5832'};
```

You can use [regexprep](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) or [strrep](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) to remove **0x** tag:

```
dummyStr = regexprep(dummyStr,'0x',''); 
floatNums = hex2num(dummyStr );
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this only works in Octave, but if you're using Octave, you're golden. ;)

---

You can do this without `regex` or stripping off the `0x` prefix. [str2double](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) will parse strings with a leading `0x` as hexadecimal numbers and convert them accordingly:

```
fileID = fopen('data.dat');
formatString = '%s %f %f %s';
data = textscan(fileID,formatString)
fclose(fileID);

data =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = 0x3
    [2,1] = 0x3
  }
  [1,2] =

     1
     3

  [1,3] =

     2
     4

  [1,4] =
  {
    [1,1] = 0x118c0832
    [2,1] = 0x118c0832
  }
}

data{1} = str2double(data{1});
data{4} = str2double(data{4});
```

Results:

```
data =
{
  [1,1] =

     3
     3

  [1,2] =

     1
     3

  [1,3] =

     2
     4

  [1,4] =

     294389810
     294389810

}
```

Comment: I keep getting `NaN` when using `str2double`. What version are you running?

Comment: @gnovice Shoot, I was afraid of that. I'm running Octave. Is `str2num` any better? I didn't want to use it since it's pretty much an `eval` clone.

Comment: Ahh, yeah. The output format should have clued me in. `str2num` doesn't appear to work either.